# Configure OpenCV on Codeblocks

Tags: opencv, build, linker, codeblocks

I would like to use OpenCV with CodeBlocks. But I don't know to configure CodeBlocks about "Project build options". I need to precise where are the headers, and functions of openCV.

Firstly I've tried to follow this tutorial : http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/ But I had some problems in the step 4 with the configuration of makefiles. In fact, I am not very sure that I need to use cmake in order to read opencv functions.

Could you help me to configure build options ? I think I need to add "C:\opencv\build\include" about compiler on Search Directories, and about linker, what should I add ? 
How add the librairy on CodeBlocks ?

Thank you

Comment: you *will* need cmake, to build the opencv libraries first. (there are no more prebuild ones for mingw)

Comment: so, for you, above tutorial actually starts with the **update in section 4

Comment: Thank you. I have already used CMake, but I have an error message. 

As the tutorial says I select C:\opencv for the source code. And C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw to build the binaries. Then I click configure. cmake ask me to specify the generator, and I answer MinGW Makefiles, and use default native compilers (it's the choose by default). 
But I have an error "The source directory "C:\opencv" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt" 
Maybe I don't have installed Opencv correctly, what do you think ? 
Thank you.

Comment: so, does it contain CMakeLists.txt ? your src folder is the one, where this file is. did you start cmake from some crazy shell, like cygwin ?

Comment: there is no 'sources' folder in the [original tree](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4). <-- see, that's the 'toplevel' folder, where you'resupposed to run it.

Comment: For my version of opencv, I have opencv/build and opencv/sources. And I have donwloaded it here : http://opencv.org/ 
But, don't worry, I have succeed my first problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In fact CMakeLists.txt is present here : ..\opencv\sources\CMakeLists.txt

I thought CMake would have searched. Then, I use correctly Cmake and he has builded OpenCV. I don't use cygwin, I use the shell of windows. So, after that, I've tried to build the exemple of opencv code in this tutorial, and it works !

Now, when I try to build a project already coded, I don't succeed. In fact, it's a code made by an other person, it use OpenCV and C++. And there is also Java code for Android. But I would like to build and execute only C++ code.

I chose the same settings for OpenCV, but how could I know what I should add in "compiler" and "linker" section ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In fact, the code was made with a Mac, and I use Windows. Don't you think there could be a problem with the difference of notation between Unix and Windows ? (About/ and \)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your source directory to `C:\opencv\sources` and see if that works.